# I get error while running python file with PySide2 and QtQuick "plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Window "

Tags: python, qml, qt-creator, pyside2, qt-quick

I just created a new project in **Qt-creator**: *"Qt for python QtQuick application"*,
When i try to run automatically generated code it throws following error

> **Error**
> *QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
> file:///C:/Users/dell/Documents/test1/qml/main.qml:2:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Window": Cannot load library C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\Library\qml\QtQuick\Window.2\windowplugin.dll: The specified procedure could not be found.*

**main.py**

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***main.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: seems anaconda bug...

Comment: @eyllanesc how can i get rid of this bug. Can you help?